GA4 measurement protocol event attribution, not working with event one week later?
I have GA4 running on my site, and in my backend I store the user's client_id and session_id. With measurement protocol on our backend, I send a custom trial started event when a user starts their trial, and I send a custom subscription paid event when a user pays for a full month. Both of these events use the same function in my code, so I know nothing is shifting between them:
# sends google analytics event
def send_ga4_event(event_name, customer_id):
    measurement_id = os.getenv("GA_MEASUREMENT_ID")
    api_secret = os.getenv("GA_MP_SECRET")
    ga_debug_mode = os.getenv("GA_DEBUG_MODE") == "true"

    user = get_user(stripe_id=customer_id, tag="send_ga4_event")
    if not user:
        logging.warn("send_ga4_event: User doesn't exist in database")
        return False
    elif not user.stripe_email:
        logging.warn("send_ga4_event: No stripe email associated with user")
        return False
    elif not user.ga_client_id:
        logging.warn("send_ga4_event: No ga_client_id associated with user")
        return False

    if not user.ga_session_id:
        logging.warn("send_ga4_event: No ga session id associated with user, continuing anyway.")
    """Send an event to GA4 with a hashed email."""
    hashed_email = hashlib.sha256(user.stripe_email.lower().encode()).hexdigest()
    params = {"debug_mode": ga_debug_mode}

    if user.ga_session_id:
        # logging.debug(f"send_ga4_event: USER {user}")
        params["session_id"] = user.ga_session_id

    event_data = {
        "client_id": user.ga_client_id,
        "user_id": hashed_email,
        "non_personalized_ads": False,
        "events": [{"name": event_name, "params": params}],
    }
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    url = f"https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id={measurement_id}&api_secret={api_secret}"

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(event_data))
    if response.ok:
        logging.debug(
            f"send_ga4_event: event_name {event_name}, customer_id {customer_id}, email {hashed_email}, measure id {measurement_id}, api secret {api_secret} [{response.status_code}, {response.text}]"
        )
        return True
    else:
        logging.error(
            f"send_ga4_event: event_name {event_name}, customer_id {customer_id}, email {hashed_email}, measure id {measurement_id}, api secret {api_secret} [{response.status_code}, {response.text}]"
        )
        return False

When I say attribution isn't correct, I mean the subscription paid event shows up in the traffic report on GA4 as 'unassigned'. This issue originally happened for trial started events too, but once I added session_id to the events, it attributed correctly.
In the data being sent, I send their client_id, user_id (which is their email hashed), and inside 'events' i send 'session_id'.
From reading the docs, I was under the impression I should be updating the session_id and client_id stored in our backend every time it's changed on their browser. The docs sound like it should connect any sessions that go back 90 days. The time between a trial start and a subscription paid is one week, so this shouldn't be an issue.
Has anyone experienced this? if so, how do you fix it?

Events can be sent for sessions that have expired, but session-related metrics will show as “not set” in GA4, even though they are present in BigQuery.
Submitting an event for a session that ended, say, more than 3  days ago, while it counts towards total events and appears in BigQuery, will reflect “not set” for metrics like landing page and session source/medium in GA4 reports. This is because sessions can not accept new events after they have expired.
also you can check other issues related to attribution not working in this medium : https://medium.com/@aliiz/navigating-measurement-protocol-challenges-and-eliminating-not-set-issues-in-ga4-a-technical-7f01863649d6

Interesting! What is the solution then? Can I pull up the equivalent of traffic report and have all the correct attribution even for events a week out? Also im just confused because GA4 says in their docs that first source will be attributed correctly up to 90 days

In BigQuery, you can create custom attributions that aren't possible in GA4. This is because GA4's Measurement Protocol (MP) and its attribution settings cannot be altered. Additionally, the 90-day lookback window in GA4 differs from your specific Issue. GA4 uses a last-non-direct attribution model to determine the source of a session. The 90-day window is the maximum period GA4 uses to look back and identify the source/medium of sessions, whether they are sent via Measurement Protocol or the data layer.

Session Id is the timestamp when a session starts on your website. So it changes everytime whenever a user starts a session on your site. One thing to keep in mind that you can not send events via measurment protocol past 72 hours after a session starts.
The default attribution window is 90 days for a key event, so this should not be an issue if you are sending accurate session details with each event.
One thing you should need to check is the source for all the unassigned traffic in your GA4 report. We are also sending our key event i.e purchase via the measurment protocol. Our payload had one custom parameter named source, that turned out was overriding the actual source of the session with the values of our custom paramerter session. So make sure you do not have something similar.
